# How to create a countdown cgi script in perl?

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm trying to create a simple cgi perl script that counts down from 10 to 0; however I can't seem to get it to work.  It keeps telling me `malformed header from script. Bad header=HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.  I'm new to Perl and CGI scripting so I'm sure it's something really simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use CGI::Push qw(:standard);

my $startingCountDown = 10;

do_push(-next_page => \&refresh, -last_page=> \&lastPage, -delay => 1 );

sub refresh
{
        my ($cgi, $count) = @_;

        return undef if ($startingCountDown - $count < 0);

        my $num = $startingCountDown - $count;
        my $page = $cgi->start_html();
        $page .= $cgi->p("The count is $num").end_html();
        return $page;
}

sub lastPage
{
     my ($cgi, $count) = @_;
    return start_html()."Blast Off".end_html();
}
```

If I run this from terminal (on my Macbook) I get the following error: `WARNING: YOUR BROWSER DOESN'T SUPPORT THIS SERVER-PUSH TECHNOLOGY.`.  I've tried running this script in both Safari and Chrome but neither seems to work.  In that case, how would I write a functioning script that counts down from 10 to 1, changing numbers every second?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "server push" mechanism that `CGI::Push` is using (specifically, `multipart/x-mixed-replace`) is not widely supported. You will need to pick a different way of implementing this; probably the best way would be to have the countdown happen in Javascript, rather than on the server side.